# NWhere are mysql data type codes defined?

Tags: mysql

Oracle uses internal codes to identify data types. For instance, FLOAT is 2, DATE is 12, etc. These codes are explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Data-Types.html

I have spent all day trying to find what codes MySQL uses internally for its data types with no luck. Any pointers appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Thanks to all who replied. Now a further question.

This page (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-data-structures.html) explains Type Value and Type Description.

So if I retrieve a row with a TINYINT column, will the type of the column be MYSQL_TYPE_TINY or TINYINT?.

I need to know the column type, as above in Oracle, so that I can map it to the correct object type.

Again thanks. MySQL is quite different than Oracle

---

And, the answer is MYSQL_TYPE_TINY.

Comment: Mysql source code can tell you this, provided mysql uses such codes to represent data types.

Comment: MySQL just uses the names in every context I know of, outside of low-level protocol or replication concerns.